# change image and caption

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to work out a way to change the text that goes along with an image that is changed with javascript...

```
var x = 0;
var images = new Array(".jpg", ".jpg", ".jpg", ".jpg", ".jpg");
var i = setInterval(auto, 10000);

function auto() {
    x++;
    if (x == images.length) x = 0;
    document.getElementById('bigImage').src = images[x];
}

function changeImage(img, imagetitle) {
    document.getElementById('bigImage').src = img;
    /* document.getElementById('mainimagetitle').innerHtml = imagetitle; */
}​​​
```

The commented part is how i suppose I could possibly change the text that goes with the image. How do i code the html. Should i use a  with the id mainimagetitle?
If so, where and how do i add the different texts i want to show and hide?

Comment: Please provide your html code so we can determine proper javascript for you.

Comment: What kind of element is the `mainimagetitle`? Try to reproduce your case in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please.

Comment: @JohnnyHankgard You can't highlight piece of code in the code block. It looks mostly like a syntax error. The edited variant is more vivid.

Answer (score 0):

As I see from your posting, this should do the job.

```
<img id="bigImage" src="img1.jpg" alt="" />
<div id="mainimagetitle"></div>
```

Be sure to add a (filled) src tag or you will get strange results in IE. As you start with the second image (x++ before the change) this will be no problem. Happy accident I think. ;-)

// Edit: Of course any element will do as long as you use the right id. But you didn't tell us what html you use (xhtml/html5/...).

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially have another array that stores the captions for each of the images

```
var captions = ['Caption 1', 'Caption 2', ...];
```

Assuming the `mainimagetitle` is an id of a `<p>` element, you could do:

```
function changeImage(img, imagetitle) {
     document.getElementById('bigImage').src = img;
     document.getElementById('mainimagetitle').innerText = imagetitle;
}​​​
```

You can see the full example, based on your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vCwWJ/).